# What steps are required to describe and graph an ellipsoid?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to describe in full details the first function in this image. I know that its an elliposid because the determinant of the 2x2 part of the G matrix is greater than 0. To graph it I should have the half-axel length, half-axel equations and eventually determine the rotation axis.

I have found the eigenvektors and egeinvalues. How may I continue this?
`E` stands for identity matrix.

[image]

Comment: Your use of the equals sign is sloppy. The matrix $G-7E$ is clearly not *equal* to the vector $(1,1,1)$, so what you are *writing* doesn't agree with what you *mean*. Instead, you can write something like $\mathbf{v}_1 = (1,1,1)$.

Comment: You are right Hans. I like to jump over the obvious steps to make things more orgnized. However, sometimes I jump over too much! Ha en trevlig dag!

Comment: Haha, detsamma! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the eigenvectors to construct an orthogonal matrix ($S$ in your notes) that will serve to diagonalize your matrix $G$. Once you have diagonalized, things get much easier. In fact, this was one of the earliest uses of eigenvectors (Cauchy). There is a good description of the details on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem).

Comment: Yes, The principal axis theorem helped me a lot! Thank you.